# SpriteKit randomly freezes on collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on my first SpriteKit game and am coming across this really frustrating bug. I have a node that is a player and a item they have to obtain. When the player collides with the item (I'm doing this check with physics bodies), the item moves to a random location on the screen.

The thing is, this collision randomly (1 in 5ish) causes the game to freeze without any errors coming up. I tried to see if any of my code was running infinite loops but the code makes it to the end of the `update:` method just fine.

So I added a bunch of print statements to different points of the SpriteKit cycle and found that it doesn't even get to `didEvaluateActions` after it freezes.

I also checked instruments to see what methods are using up the CPU (when it freezes it goes up to 100%), and this is what I found:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to pause the app in Xcode? If not you can find the pause button right above your console logs. Sometimes that will help identify where it is locking up. Also showing your logs and/or your collision logic might help other identify your issue.

Comment: You need to pepper the relevant parts of your code with NSLog statements to see where your code gets stuck. Your question is impossible to answer in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that the root of the problem was happening when the program was evaluating actions based on the picture [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

The cause of the freezing was an infinite loop I created by accident by calling an action forever with a time of `arc4random() % 5`, which creates an infinite loop when it comes out to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can write `arc4random() % 5 + 1` which means the system generates a random number between 1 and 5. It doesn't return 0 again.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing haha